# Android Studio Emulator, swipe to unlock doesn't

Tags: android

Recently upgraded to Java 1.8, and latest Android Studio -
Broke everything.
Took awhile to get the jdk to be recognized with mucking about in the Environment Variables.
I am quickly approaching the "reinstall everything" state but wish to avoid that if possible.

When I run Android Studio and just start up any emulator *api 18 - 22* the mouse swipe to unlock (or scroll through screens) does not work.  I feel like I'm missing something simple in a configuration somewhere.   I get the animations as if the emulator sees my mouse down and gesture but isn't doing anything with the mouse up.  Or if scrolling a screen of icons it just opens the program instead of seeing my mouse is still down and gesturing.

Windows 8.1, Android Studio 1.1, Java 1.8.0_40 (does same thing when I change env var to use java 1.7x)

Thanks for any advice.
Susan

Comment: Restart the machine. It sounds like it's just a mouse issue.

Comment: I am both horrified and amused.  Apparently my wireless mouse on/off wasn't entirely in the ON position...  *blushing*  THANK YOU.  I can move on with my life now.